Using Google Play Developer API to determine if app is released
I would like to get notified programmatically when the app is published to production track.
At the moment Im polling for changes using Google Play Developer API in following way:

I create a new edit for production track or use existing edit if it's still valid (I store android_edit_id and android_edit_expires_at)
get the track details
read the status of the build and determine if this is the last build we sent

A pseudo-code in node js:
const internalResponse = await androidPublisher.edits.tracks.get({
    auth,
    packageName,
    track: "production",
    editId: editId,
});
log("Internal response", { internalResponse: internalResponse.data });

const lastBuildCodes = internalResponse.data.releases?.[0]?.versionCodes;
log("Last edit", { lastBuildCodes, data: internalResponse.data });
// parse list of strings to numbers and find biggest number
let currentBuildNumber = 0;
if (lastBuildCodes) {
    for (const buildCode of lastBuildCodes) {
        const buildNumber = Number(buildCode);
        if (buildNumber > currentBuildNumber) {
            currentBuildNumber = buildNumber;
        }
    }
}
log("Build number:", currentBuildNumber);

However, there are some problems with this approach (see more here)

there's a limit to number of edits created in a given day, so I have to limit the API to updates every 2 hours;
if the app gets published within the edit expiry my edit is still valid, and indicates previous build number

Is there any other -- read-only -- way to get the current build available in a given track? Has anyone had any success with scraping the console (which I would like to avoid)?
I was also considering parsing the e-mail notifications and trigger the edits API only then to avoid polling issues.
